# Is it better to use `StandardScaler` before using `MinMaxScaler`?

Tags: scikit-learn, feature-scaling

in sklearn, if I want to transform the data to range(-1, 1), do you think it is better to use `StandardScaler` before using `MinMaxScaler`? to make the date more normal distributed?

Comment: `StandardScaler()` is affine linear, so there is no reason to do so.

Comment: Both of the proposed scalers are linear transformations, and the composition of linear functions is also linear. That's addressed in the second duplicate. The first duplicate explains that neither one of these will make data resemble a normal distribution, because these scalers cannot change the shape of the data. We have many, many threads about making data more normally distributed; they can be found by using the Search feature: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=+data+normally+distributed+score%3A3+answers%3A1